# How to connect mysql in Hostinger to my local workbench?

Tags: mysql, connection, mysql-workbench

I have database in my hostinger account i need to connect in my local workbench for my development purpose. anyone kindly assist me to connect.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone having trouble with this my problem was just the `username`.
When we create a username its also like a database name its being concatenated sample `78787878_username`. When trying to connect to workspace the full username.
make sure also aready setup the `remote mysql` in hostinger database

Answer (score -1):

Workbench new connection setup:

[image]
**Connection Name:** you will identify the connection in MySQL Workbench. This is only a name in your personal MySQL Workbench application.

---

**Hostname:** This is your database's server. This will be normally a URL pointing to the database.

---

**Port**: The Port that Hostinger normally use for MySQL is 3306.

---

**Username**: This is your database username generated.

---

**Password**: This is the password generated for your database.